# Adding Views Between Items in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have a scrollable GridView where the items have a decent amount of empty space between them. for some of the objects in the grid, I'd like to add arrow images leading from one to the other

For reference to what I mean, think of the World of Warcraft talent trees (http://calculators.iradei.eu/talents/mage). You'll see some of the talents have arrows leading from one item to the next.

The layout I'm dealing with just contains a gridview in a framelayout, nothing else

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/talent_tree_grid_view">
    </GridView>

</FrameLayout>
```

I'm trying to add these ImageViews in code, as I don't think there is any way I could add this logic into the adapter for the GridView.

I've tried adding them as children of the parent FrameLayout, based on the x and y coords of the GridView items, and this works, but when scrolling the GridView, the arrows do not also scroll

I've also tried adding them directly as children of the GridView, but it does not support this behavior (it throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException)

Are there any ideas as to how I could add these imageviews between the gridview items?

Comment: You might want to extend GridLayout and add your own drawing

Comment: one thing you can do you can add the arrow image into your gridview item and show them whenever certain conditions meet but I don't that will be much appropriate.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a demo project.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds very similar to Romain Guy's "Shelves" app where a custom `GridView` is used and the background image of a bookshelf scrolls. Take a look at the project [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/shelves/). Source for the custom GridView can be found in the file `ShelvesView.java` in the source code. A quick intro from Guy Romain is [here](http://www.curious-creature.com/2009/01/19/shelves-an-open-source-android-application/);

For the arrows, you may want to consider a [9-patch drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html).

---

I have investigated the above approach a little more and have a sample app based upon 
Google's [Hello GridView example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html#example).

Taking this example app, I have built a custom GridView (DogsGridView.java) and connected the photos across empty cells similar to your example of World of Warcraft talent trees. I just use simple lines, but the class can be modified to connect cells with arrows or another graphic.

Here is a [quick video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mBSt.gif) with connecting lines. Here is [another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyPoW.gif) with 9-patch arrows.

The project source can be found [here](https://github.com/Cheticamp/HelloGridView).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Cheticamp! It worked, but I had performance issues, while scrolling, as the connecting arrows were constantly being redrawn I think? I may end up implementing a solution which involves drawing the pieces of the arrows within the grid view items (which are framelayouts in my case). So the item from which the arrow originates would have the first part of the arrow, any empty grid spaces between would have middle sections, and the final grid item where the arrow ends would have the end point of the arrow. I will post that answer here if I get it working properly.

Comment: @Dportology I don't know when you pulled the source, but I made some performance improvements yesterday by pulling a call to the super of `dispathDraw` out of the child inspection loop. I saw a significant improvement on my emulator after that. Rather than splitting up the graphic and putting it inside the grid view items, you may want to consider drawing the maximum graphic once inside the custom `GridView` and just cropping and copying it as needed.

Comment: @Dportology The arrows were being drawn multiple times because of the way I did the looping. I have change the search to follow down columns instead of rows, so this should perform much better. Each visible position should be considered just once. GitHub has the updates.